# Javascript filter array whitin array with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is my outcome from the server.

```
arrays= 
      [ 0: 
        { Id: 1
        , name: 'test1'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 1: 
        { Id: 2
        , name: 'test2'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'disk_init',         type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 2:
        { Id: 3
        , name: 'test3'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 3: 
        { Id: 4
        , name: 'test4'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 5:
        { Id: 5
        , name: 'test5'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial_disk_init', type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_initial',      type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
          ] 
         } 
      ]
```

And i need to filter it with multiple conditions.

```
filters = {
  application_name: 'initial',
  application_role: 'disk_init_role'
}
```

I made a function to filter the data but this works only with one condition

```
  filterArray (array, filters) {
    for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(filters)) {
      const res = Object.values(array).filter(
        item => item.parameters.some(param => param.name === `${key}` && param.value === `${value}`)
      )

      return results

    }
}
```

What is the best way to loop through the array so both contions (filters) are met?
The outcome needs to be only id 1 and 4 and thats needs to be in a return results array.

Comment: What do you mean by "this works only with one condition" ?
I don't see any problem with your filter function if it only needs to check the "name" and "key" properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are looking for every item in `arrays` every item matches what your `filters` contains.

For this you can use `every` method on the `filters` and attempt to `find` the item with that `name` and match the `value`

```
const result = arrays.filter(item => {
   return Object.entries(filters)
                .every( ([key,value]) => item.parameters.find(p => p.name == key).value == value)
});
```

Live example:

```js
const arrays= 
      [  
        { Id: 1
        , name: 'test1'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      ,  
        { Id: 2
        , name: 'test2'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'disk_init',         type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 
        { Id: 3
        , name: 'test3'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      ,  
        { Id: 4
        , name: 'test4'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial',           type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_init_role',    type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
        ] } 
      , 
        { Id: 5
        , name: 'test5'
        , parameters: 
          [ { name: 'application_instance', value: 'home',              type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_name',     value: 'initial_disk_init', type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'application_role',     value: 'disk_initial',      type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_environment', value: 'development',       type: 'generic' } 
          , { name: 'customer_name',        value: 'guest',             type: 'generic' } 
          ] 
         } 
      ]

const filters = {
  application_name: 'initial',
  application_role: 'disk_init_role'
}


const result = arrays.filter(item => {
   return Object.entries(filters).every( ([key,value]) => item.parameters.find(p => p.name == key).value == value)
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thx for your help this seems to work.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This applies all the filters to each of the array elements. Only when all filter conditions are met, the array element is added to the result array.

```js
const arrays= [
  {
    "0": {
      "Id": 1,
      "name": "test1",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "application_instance",
          "value": "home",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_name",
          "value": "initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_role",
          "value": "disk_init_role",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_environment",
          "value": "development",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_name",
          "value": "guest",
          "type": "generic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "Id": 2,
      "name": "test2",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "application_instance",
          "value": "home",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_name",
          "value": "disk_init",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_role",
          "value": "initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_environment",
          "value": "development",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_name",
          "value": "guest",
          "type": "generic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "Id": 3,
      "name": "test3",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "application_instance",
          "value": "home",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_name",
          "value": "initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_role",
          "value": "initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_environment",
          "value": "development",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_name",
          "value": "guest",
          "type": "generic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "3": {
      "Id": 4,
      "name": "test4",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "application_instance",
          "value": "home",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_name",
          "value": "initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_role",
          "value": "disk_init_role",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_environment",
          "value": "development",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_name",
          "value": "guest",
          "type": "generic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "5": {
      "Id": 5,
      "name": "test5",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "application_instance",
          "value": "home",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_name",
          "value": "initial_disk_init",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "application_role",
          "value": "disk_initial",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_environment",
          "value": "development",
          "type": "generic"
        },
        {
          "name": "customer_name",
          "value": "guest",
          "type": "generic"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
const filters = {
  application_name: 'initial',
  application_role: 'disk_init_role'
};

const result = arrays.filter((e) => {
  const parameters = e[Object.keys(e)[0]].parameters;
  let match = true;
  Object.keys(filters).forEach((f) => {
    const parameter = parameters.find((g) => g.name === f);
    match = match && parameter.value === filters[f];
  });
  return match;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you want any of the filter condition will match

```
arr.filter(el => {
    const res = el.parameters.find(perameter => { 
        return filters[perameter.name] == perameter.value;
    });
    return !!res;
});
```

And use this code if you want all the filter conditions should match.

```
arr.filter(el => {
    const res = el.parameters.filter(perameter => { 
        return filters[perameter.name] == perameter.value;
    });
    return res.length === Object.keys(filters).length;
});
```

Comment: why not use `some` and `every` - that's what they're for.

Comment: because If we implement this with ```some``` and ```every``` method then we have use an extra loop, like your code has 3 loops and my code have 2 loops, Which I think is not efficient.